# How to select a row in the middle of a table and select all rows after it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I want select from the last row to the first row of a database, I use `SELECT * FROM Gallery ORDER BY ID DESC`, but I want select the third row from last to first such as this code:

```
$LastRowID = 20;

$FindRows = mysqli_query($Database,"SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY ID DESC");
$FindLastRow = mysqli_query($Database,"SELECT * FROM Table Where ID = /* $LastRowID - 3 */ ORDER BY ID DESC");
```

When this code is running it just selects only $LastRowID - 3 row, but I need to select all row after $LastRowID - 3;

What is the way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can do `WHERE ID >= $LastRowID`

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question but you could look at the LIMIT clause.

Comment: Do you want to have the last three rows? In this case I would use your first query and add _limit 3_. If you want anything before the last 3 rows, you might still use the first query and skip the first three result rows. But your question is not clear to me.

Comment: Oh, Thanks, I Forget it, thanks andrewsi , it's true

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way...

```
  SELECT * FROM ints;
  +---+
  | i |
  +---+
  | 0 |
  | 1 |
  | 2 |
  | 3 |
  | 4 |
  | 5 |
  | 6 |
  | 7 |
  | 8 |
  | 9 |
  +---+

  SELECT * FROM ints ORDER BY i DESC LIMIT 3,100000;
  +---+
  | i |
  +---+
  | 6 |
  | 5 |
  | 4 |
  | 3 |
  | 2 |
  | 1 |
  | 0 |
  +---+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.* FROM
( SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 3) AS x
ORDER BY x.Id LIMIT 1
```

This should get you the row with the third highest Id.